# How can I disable the DefaultButton of an asp:Panel at ClientSide?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, panel, jquery-events, preventdefault

I have an `asp:Panel` whose default button is set to **Save** button of the form. But I want that when the focus is on one specific anchor element in my form, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key should not fire the **DefaultButton** of Panel. Rather it should fire the Javascript function written inside the `href` of the anchor, which perfectly works if I just remove the `asp:Panel` from the form.

I have tried many solutions, but none of them seems to work. Some of them are:-

1. I capture the **focus** event of anchor in which I hook another handler for **keypress** event and use `event.preventDefault()` so that event is cancelled there only and remove that `keypress` event on the `blur` of anchor element. But this does not stop the `DefaultButton` of **Panel** from being executed.
2. Use another `asp:Panel` inside the outer **Panel** and set its `DefaultButton` to the `ImageButton` which replaces the **anchor element**(because we can not set `DefaultButton` to *anchor*). - But this still fires the `DefaultButton` of the outside **Panel**.

What I need is some way to disable the `DefaultButton` of the outer `asp:Panel` at the Client Side. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are doing, but when you add a DefaultButton attribute to an `asp:Panel` then it adds something like this to the rendered div:

```
onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;Button1&#39;)"
```

You can remove that attribute using jQuery by doing something like:

```
$("#Panel1").removeAttr("onkeypress");
```

(Assuming the ClientID of your Panel is `Panel1`). Hope that is of some help!

Comment: I already solved the problem before I looked up this solution, through some alternate way, but this is the exact answer of my question. Therefore +1 and accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are hitting a typical limitation when using the asp.net controls to generate Javascript.

I would write your own function to handle the submission of this form and then put the necessary logic inside of that.